# How to connect Elements with 2D Arrays

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create a map in the shape of grid 4 columns X 5 Rows  and connect each rooms together. Below code compiles but when I try to run it it comes up with the error. Could anyone please tell me where its gone wrong? Thanks.

```
  public static final int NUM_ROOMS = 20; 

  public static final int NUM_COLS = 4; 

  private ArrayList<Room> myRooms;

  public Map(){

     int row =0;
     ArrayList<Room> myRooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
     while (row<NUM_COLS){
        int i =0;
        i = row % NUM_COLS;
        while(i+1<NUM_COLS){
           while (i+1 <(row+1)% NUM_COLS){
              Room r1 = myRooms.get(i);
              Room r2 = myRooms.get(i+1);
              r1.connectTo(r2);
              r2.connectTo(r1);
              i++;
           }
           row++;
        }

        int col = 0;

        while (col<NUM_COLS){
           i = col; 
           while (i+4<NUM_ROOMS){
             i = i+NUM_COLS; 
            }
            col++;
        }

     }

 }
```

Comment: whats the exception ?? .. please post your stacktrace

Comment: @user1721548.. Pre-defined class or interface, are parts of the Java. They have their functionality.. But if use name your class with their name, it won't be any problem, until you start using the pre-defined one.. And your class name is `Map` which is a pre-defined `Interface`..  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: @RohitJain I don't think you should bother too much about such minor naming conflicts in school. Sure, in a large scale production environment I would agree that naming your class Map is a bad idea, since experienced programmers will make incorrect assumptions about its functionality. In a school examples, that is not the case, though. And when you're new to Java, there are many things which are much more important than ensuring that there is no class with the same name in the JavaSE library. Such considerations can be made later, when you have gotten more acquainted with those libraries.

Comment: @RohitJain I have written numerous variants of classes like Stack, LinkedList, Queue etc. all merely intended for school. But since it's just for school, the fact that those classes have names which conflict with JavaSE classes/interfaces doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Alderath.. Ok Ok.. It was just a suggestion man.. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `myRooms` list is empty. So when you try to get an element out of the list, you get an exception. You have to use something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROOMS; i++) {
    myRooms.add(new Room());
}
```

to populate the list first.